# How to attach multiple pdfs from directory (in server) to email attachments in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email, pdf, email-attachments

I made a form that can send form details to database then convert results to pdf (*pdfcrowd).
I have saved the filename(*of the pdf) inside the database and the pdf is saved inside a folder directory too.

Everything is working fine. EXCEPT that i'm stuck on how to get the pdf files. 
The user is going to see the tables. I'll provide a checkbox and when the checkbox is clicked, the filename in the row should be included on what to attach in the email.

My database is Recipes, Table: Recipe_list, The field where filename is saved is.. "recipe_name" and the folder where the pdfs files are inside "/recipes/" folder.

I don't understand the "MIME" and other stuff about email attachment. I would appreciate if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer below link for this task,

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/07/22/sending-email-with-multiple-attachments-with-php/

this would be very much helpful to you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link. IT'S WORKING 101% :D!